# TensorFlow/Keras model errors out when trying to predict, citing shape mismatch, though the shape I provide seems correct

Tags: python, image, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I am not sure if I don’t understand the input tensor ideas well or if I trained the model with wrong input shapes, or if I need to specify images in a certain way.

The model is built as follows:

```
... import all the usual libraries - TF, Keras, Numpy, OpenCV etc. ...
_MODEL_DIMENSION = 128

def create_model_for_dimension(dimension):
    model = Sequential()
    if dimension >= 256:
        model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5, 5), input_shape=(dimension, dimension, 3)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    if dimension >= 128:
        model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3)))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
…… more convolution layers ……..
…………………………………………..
……………………………………………..
    model.add(Flatten())
……… More layers …………………
……………………………………………..
……………………………………………..

    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=10,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=1.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_directory, 
        target_size=(_MODEL_DIMENSION, _MODEL_DIMENSION),
        batch_size=_BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode='categorical')

……… validate_generator …………………
……………………………………………………
………………………………………………………
……… test_generator ………………………
………………………………………………………
………………………………………………………

……… train and save the model ……
```

When I trained and used it to predict on images from a directory, everything worked (or seemed to, at least). But I then tried to feed in an image without using the ImageDataGenerator in the following way:

First, I read the image using OpenCV (I expect to do other processing using OpenCV, so am not using PIL)

```
ml_model = … read the model back from the saved model ……
snapshot = cv.imread(file_name)
snapshot = cv.cvtColor(snapshot, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Then I crop the image using ranges

```
cropped_area = snapshot[y[0]:y[1], x[0]:x[1]]
```

Then I score using the model as follows. I also tried variants other than np.array conversion.

```
score_val = model.predict(np.array(cropped_area/255.0))
```

This is when it errors out as follows:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [32, 128, 3]
```

My image's shape is (128, 128, 3), and all the checks I made seem to confirm that that is what I have been feeding it.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, since I have spent the better part of the day trying to troubleshoot this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You set `_MODEL_DIMENSION = 128`

which leads to

```
if dimension >= 128:
        model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3)))
```

You do not set an input shape, so according to the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) the expected input will be:

> Input shape
>
> 4D tensor with shape: (batch, channels, rows, cols) if data_format is "channels_first" or 4D tensor with shape: (batch, rows, cols, channels) if data_format is "channels_last".

Your input doesn't fit, hence the error

> expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

The solution is to define an input shape, which already exists in your code:

```
if dimension >= 256:
        model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5, 5), input_shape=(dimension, dimension, 3)))
```

Comment: This was the problem, thanks. The lesson learned is not to parameterize the model to reduce lines of code, especially when (which is the case here) the different sizes are handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is missing the batch dimension. Your model needs 4D data, not 3D.

Your image shape should be `(1, 128,128, 3)`